# qemu and virtio-vga black screen in Android

Tags: android, kvm-virtualization, qemu

```
QEMU emulator version 4.0.0 (Debian 1:4.0+dfsg-0ubuntu9.3)
kernel 5.3.0-29-generic
host Ubuntu 19.10
guest: Android 8.1
```

While trying to run

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive media=cdrom,readonly,file=Downloads/android-x86_64-8.1-r3-k49.iso -drive if=virtio,id=disk0,cache=none,format=raw,aio=threads,file=android.img -machine ubuntu,accel=kvm -m 2048 -soundhw es1370 -boot menu=on -device virtio-vga,virgl=on -display gtk,gl=on
```

I only get a black screen

while trying to run

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive media=cdrom,readonly,file=Downloads/android-x86_64-8.1-r3-k49.iso -drive if=virtio,id=disk0,cache=none,format=raw,aio=threads,file=android.img -machine ubuntu,accel=kvm -m 2048 -soundhw es1370 -boot menu=on -vga virtio
```

I can start Android, however, it does not start the GUI.

However it runs using the VGA adapter

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive media=cdrom,readonly,file=Downloads/android-x86_64-8.1-r3-k49.iso -drive if=virtio,id=disk0,cache=none,format=raw,aio=threads,file=android.img -machine ubuntu,accel=kvm -m 2048 -soundhw es1370 -boot menu=on -vga std -device VGA,vgamem_mb=128
```

I would like to use virtio in order to be able to use higher resolutions than 1024x768.

I believe it is a bug but I just want to make sure before reporting it

Answer (score 0):

instead of

> qemu-system-x86_64 -drive media=cdrom,readonly,file=Downloads/android-x86_64-8.1-r3-k49.iso -drive if=virtio,id=disk0,cache=none,format=raw,aio=threads,file=android.img -machine ubuntu,accel=kvm -m 2048 -soundhw es1370 -boot menu=on -device virtio-vga,virgl=on **-display gtk**,gl=on

use

> qemu-system-x86_64 -drive media=cdrom,readonly,file=Downloads/android-x86_64-8.1-r3-k49.iso -drive if=virtio,id=disk0,cache=none,format=raw,aio=threads,file=android.img -machine ubuntu,accel=kvm -m 2048 -soundhw es1370 -boot menu=on -device virtio-vga,virgl=on **-display sdl**,gl=on

you **might** need to use [qemu-virgil](https://snapcraft.io/qemu-virgil) package to get sdl support(or build from source.[see this for reference](https://youtu.be/bz8FugjsHs8))

Script i use for my android vm for reference.(it works like a charm)

> qemu-system-x86_64 -boot c -enable-kvm -smp 3 -device virtio-vga,virgl=on  -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::4444-:5555 -cpu host -soundhw es1370 -m 4096 -display sdl,gl=on -hda /home/username/Ntfs/Other/VDK/Android9.img